# PHP MySQL: Go through each row, and count how many columns meet criteria

Tags: php, mysql, count

I've got a table similar to:

```
|       | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
|-------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| user1 | 100     | 49      | 3       | 1,980   |
| user2 | 7       | 5       | 51      | 500     |
| user3 | 1       | 65      | 44      | 37      |
```

I want to go through all the rows, and for each of those rows, I want to select the `count()` relating to how many columns meet a criteria (`value < 100`, for example)

So the result of each row calculating `value < 100` would be:

```
user1: 2
user2: 3
user3: 4
```

Does anyone have an idea how to go about this? I can't seem to find any answers for a question this specific.

Thanks!

Comment: `((column1 < 100) + (column2 < 100) + (column3  < 100) + (column4 < 100)) as total`

Answer (score 0):

I totally forgot about just doing a simple, hardcoded query.

This solution works for me:

```
SELECT user,              (column1 < 100) +
                          (column2 < 100) +
                          (column3 < 100) +
                          (column4 < 100)
AS total FROM table;
```

Thanks to the commenters - I had overlooked this simple solution.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted so as to keep this question off the unanswered questions list.

Comment: I will! Can't accept my own answer until tomorrow though :(